# If someone had a family tradition that he came from an Edomite, would he be allowed to marry a Jew?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, marriage, conversion-to-judaism, communities

An Edomite [cannot](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/general/daily-rambam/092.htm) marry a Jew for three generations.

Nowadays (since the time of Sancheiriv, who mixed all nations together), this law no longer applies as we no longer know who is an Edomite. However, there were people who had a tradition of their lineage. For example, Haman was a known Amaleiki,. If someone had a tradition that they were one of the "original Edomites" or "original Moabites", would he be prohibited to marry a Jewess?

Answer (score 2):

He would be allowed to marry in. It's an explicit [Mishna in Yadayim 4:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%93_%D7%93)

Comment: @DoubleAA, the mishna implies a case where the ger came from that land.  Would it make a difference if he had a mesorah that predated Sancheriv?

Comment: It could be that the Amoni didn't have a tradition (he may have just lived in the place called Amon).

Comment: You got me: this could be a national origin and not a tradition. But 1) I'm not sure those were so different back then; and 2) I doubt you will find a better source.